# Filter date time POSIXct data

Tags: r, date, datetime, filter, tidyverse

I am trying to filter a large dataset down to records that occur on the hour. The data looks like this:
[image: data example image.]

I want to filter the `Date_Time` field to be only the records that are on the hour i.e. "yyyy-mm-dd XX:00:00" or within 10 min of the hour. So, for example, this dataset would reduce down to row 1 and 5. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the minute value from datetime and select the rows which is within 10 minutes.

```
result <- subset(df, as.integer(format(UTC_datetime, '%M')) <= 10)
```

Or with `dplyr` and `lubridate` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

result <- df %>% filter(minute(UTC_datetime) <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[minute(UTC_datetime)<=10]
```